# How to add Linear Layout to be always the first element in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a RecyclerView with CardView which display the data read from the database.And this have no problem with it.

Now the problem is,I want to add a Linear layout which content both ImageView and TextView inside in the same RecyclerView,and make it always the First Element in the RecyclerView.

This is what I want to acheive.The first element in the RecyclerView is always the Linear Layout,no matter what different in the CardView below it.

[image: what i want to acheive]

I try this tutorial from [this link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView#creating-the-complexrecyclerviewadapter) it seems like handle the different ViewType depends of the data from the database,which is not what I want.

**What I want is**

1) This Linear Layout is static

2) Always the First element in the RecyclerView.

I check `if(index == 0) in`onCreateViewHolder`the index just not recognised by the android studio.

```
 @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(index== 0) {
            View feedInput = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.feed_input, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(feedInput);
        }else {
            View feedItemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(feedItemView);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why does the LinearLayout need to be IN the RecyclerView? Can you just put it on top?

Comment: @MichaelVescovo I need it inside the recycle view,so it can be scroll up when the recyclerview is being scrolled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by creating a layout containing both `LinearLayout` and `CardView` let us call it `both_layout`. Keep the visibility of LinearLayout `GONE`.

```
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = (View) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.both_layout, parent, false);
    // Inflate both the layout.
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        holder.makeFirst();
    }
}
```

In your `ViewHolder.makeFirst` make `LinearLayout` visible and remove `CardView`.

```
public void makeFirst() {
    linearlayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    cardView.setVisibility(GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the linearLayout to be always visible, even if recyclerView is scrolled, you can put the LinearLayout outside the RecyclerView.
Do something like:

```
<RelativeLayout
--your attribute-->

    <LinearLayout 
    --your attributes-->
        //Your LinearLayout elements here
    </LinearLayout>

    <RecyclerView
    --your attributes--/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If the linearlayout needs to be the first element of your list you can check the position in the adapter, if it's the first position (index == 0), inflate the layout with your `LinearLayout`, else inflate with the list item layout you alredy using.

EDIT:

Here's an example:

Just implement `getItemViewType()`, and take care of the `viewType` parameter in `onCreateViewHolder()`.

So you do something like:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
}
```

then in `onCreateViewHolder` inflate your different layout according to your `viewType`.

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == 1) {
        // inflate your first item layout & return that viewHolder
    } else {
        // inflate your second item layout & return that viewHolder
    }
}
```

Comment: means that `if(index == 0)` then inflate my linear layout,else inflate the card view,am I right??

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I try to check the `if(index==0)` but it seems like the index is unknown,not recognized

Comment: By index i mean the current position. That is the one in the onBindViewHolder. There you have to check and inflate

Comment: can u show me how to inflate the layout in `onBindViewHolder`?It seem cant inflate in `onBindViewHolder` here

Comment: Cause as I see I can only inflate in `onCreateViewHolder` isnt it??

Comment: I will give you a code sample. Give me a few minutes

Comment: Edit the answer !

Comment: @AngeloParente I liked your idea to use `getItemViewType`.

Comment: @Shreyash Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

You should look for `viewType`, no `index` :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    class LinearViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public LinearViewHolder(View itemView){
        View feedInput = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.feed_input, parent, false);
            return new LinearViewHolder(feedInput);
        }
    }

    class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView){
        View feedItemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(feedItemView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       return position;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         if(viewType == 0) {
             return new LinearViewHolder();
         } else {
              return new ItemViewHolder();
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if(holder.getItemViewType() == 0) {
             LinearViewHolder linearHolder = LinearViewHolder(holder);
         } else {
              ItemViewHolder itemHolder = ItemViewHolder(holder);
         }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.